# How does one make a html scrolling page

Tags: html, css

So basically, this sounds similar to another question but hear me out; What I want is one photo to be stuck there, and that I can scroll in it, if you are having trouble understanding here's an example: [www.starwars.com](http://www.starwars.com)

If you see carefully, you can see that there is a space background anchored and elements (Videos and Images) that I can scroll.

Any sort of help will be appreciated.

Comment: that website uses a static background and elements with a different background. Not sure what you mean.

Comment: You want the `background-attachment: fixed` property with the image as a background of your scrollable element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I think you're getting at is CSS background attachment.

Suppose you have a large background image... we'll call it `background.webp` for this example.  You might put something like this in your CSS:

```
body {
  background-image: url("background.webp");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

This will set the image to be the background (`background-image`), lock it so it doesn't scroll with the content (`background-attachment`), center the image (`background-position`), prevent it from repeating (`background-repeat`), and resize it so it covers the whole viewport (`background-size`).

Answer (score 1):

in order to have a fixed background you can use `background-attachment: fixed;` in css, the same goes for other elements such as your navbar you can use `position: fixed;`

here is an example for you

```css
    body  {
      background-image: url("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;
    }
    
    
    .navbar {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .navbar a {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
    }
    
    .navbar a:hover {
      background: #ddd;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .main {
      padding: 16px;
      margin-top: 30px;
      height: 1500px; 
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="navbar">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#news">News</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="main">
      <h1>Fixed Top Menu</h1>
      <h2>Scroll this page to see the effect</h2>
      <h2>The navigation bar will stay at the top of the page while scrolling</h2>
    
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is quite helpful, makes it more clear. :)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please always give a sufficient explanation of your anwser so it can be undertsood and reproduced. Anwsers without sufficient explanation are considered low-quality for SO.

Comment: hi @tacoshy thanks for the tip, ill work on that

Answer (score 0):

check out this one you understand properly

1. The background-attachment property sets whether a background image
   scrolls with the rest of the page or are fixed.

CSS syntax:

```
background-attachment: scroll|fixed|local|initial|inherit;
```

Helpful  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-attachment